# Nimzowitsch specific game with Nf6-g8

Tags: master-games

Is there any way to search for games by a player where the move "x...Ng8" took place?

I'm looking for a specific game.

And no, it's not Saemisch - Nimzowitsch, Berlin 1928.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do that in Chessbase. I'm not aware of a free tool that does that.

Comment: @Brian I have Chessbase. I don't know the exact position, however.

Comment: Check 'Chess Query Language' on your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 4):

If you have your database in clear text format such as pgn, and if you are satisfied with any knight move to g8, you could just search for the string "Ng8" (and potentially "Nfg8", "Nhg8" and "Neg8") in the pgn.

This does not help if you want to filter for Nf6g8 *only*, unless there is a way to save the pgn with long algebraic notation. Also you would find both black and white knights moving to g8 (probably a lot more black than white moves though).

Comment: When I search Nimzowitsch but put in free search text "ng8", nothing pops up. I have ChessBase for Android.

Comment: I was not talking about chessbase. (No idea what its free search text does.) What I meant is to open the pgn in an editor (e.g notepad) and search there.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with chess database softwares 
Paid and open-source like chessbase or scid chess.

You do not need to put complete position, also you can use maneuvers if you know last move.
Here is a [Link](https://en.chessbase.com/post/fun-and-instructive-the-new-search-mask-in-chessbase-15) to chessbase with instructions